# Wordpress Enqueue Style Plugin via Class

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm having difficulties adding a front end style from a plugin.

I have the following class created:

```
class CCYTFeatured {

     public function __construct(){
         add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'cc_yt_scripts' ));
     }


     // Load CSS FRONT
     public function cc_yt_scripts() {
             wp_register_style( 'cc_yt-style',
                     plugins_url( '/css/cc_yt.css', __FILE__ )
                );
            wp_enqueue_style('cc_yt-style');

     }
}
```

I'm then calling the class in a theme page:

```
$cc_yt = new CCYTFeatured;
```

I know the class is called correctly because i can pass strings through the constructor and they output correctly.

Please help,

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found my mistake.

I m not firing

> cc_yt_scripts()

My updated  __contruct() function now looks like this:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->cc_yt_scripts();
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'cc_yt_scripts' ));
}
```

Hope it helps someone. x)